# Javascript function for MAC Address's mask

Tags: javascript, react-native, mask, mac-address, react-native-paper

I made this question because i was recently looking for a String Mask for Mac address. So i decided to create my own function.
Previous code:

```
import React from 'react'
import {TextInput} from 'react-native-paper'
import {TextInputMask} from 'react-native-masked-text'
.
.
.
 <TextInput
            mode="outlined"
            label="MAC"

            render={props =>
                <TextInputMask
                    type={'custom'}
                    options={{
                        /**
                         * mask: (String | required | default '')
                         * the mask pattern
                         * 9 - accept digit.
                         * A - accept alpha.
                         * S - accept alphanumeric.
                         * * - accept all, EXCEPT white space.
                        */
                        mask: 'AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA'
                    }}
                    {...props}
                />
```

The problem was when I type the Mac Address slowly, the mask erases the text, and this behavior is pretty annoying. It just works well when I type the Mac address faster and this doesn't happen on regular use flow.
Ps: I was using 'react-native-masked-text'

Comment: It looks like you use some templating framework. Please add the appropriate tag to your question.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
export function macAddressMask(input){
    const MAC_ADDRESS_WITH_MASK = 17
    const setCharacters = new Set(["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f","A","B","C","D","E","F"])
    let res = ""
    let idxAtMask= -1
    for(let idx=0;idx<input.length;idx++){
        let currChar = input.charAt(idx)
        if(setCharacters.has(currChar)){
            if(idxAtMask===1){
                res+=":"
                idxAtMask = -1
            }
            res +=currChar
            idxAtMask++

        }
    }

    if(res.length <= MAC_ADDRESS_WITH_MASK){
        return res
    }else{
        return res.substr(0,MAC_ADDRESS_WITH_MASK)
    }
}
```

using with TextInput from 'react-native-paper':

```
import {macAddressMask} from '../util/util-masks'
.
.
.
 <TextInput
            mode="outlined"
            label="MAC addresss"
            value={(parentState['macAddress'])}
            onChangeText={(text) => {
                setParentState('macAddress', macAddressMask(text))
            }}
        />
```

Comment: Don't post additional information as an answer, update your question to include the information instead.

Comment: There is no additional function at the answer. The answer just contains my solution and a use-case  example

Comment: So the issue is resolved in this answer then? If so, you should mark it as such so that it can work as a resource for anyone having the same issue in the future.